# Google Maps not showing option to Add Stop

Tags: android, google-maps

I am generating a URL for multiple directions
i.e. https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Address1/Address2/Address3/

And I am passing this URL to Intent Map Activity. This opens the Map Application with a Route containing multiple Stops within Origin and Destination.

But, In some of the devices, Map Application is not having the option for Multiple Directions i.e. "Add Stop" option. Since The Map Application is updated to the latest version available, still it doesn't have this feature by default.

To be specific, Tablets doesn't have this feature, whereas All Mobile phones are having this feature when Map is updated.

But, when I generate this URL and opens it directly through Maps; It adds this feature to the Maps Application.

Can anybody help me with this ??
Why tablets are not having "Add Stop" option even in the updates version ??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "why does an app not have feature X" is not a suitable question for SO

Comment: I know. But, this is Google Maps I am talking about here. Google has added this feature in the latest update. But, Tablets do not have this feature by default. So, I thought of it as an issue and wanted to see if anybody can help. Thanks